# Connecting to AWS SNS from Azure Logic Apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-logic-apps, amazon-sns

All,

One of our vendor is moving to **AWS** from **Azure** we are now required to connect to their **AWS SNS** and read the messages from the Topic. We would like to use the same **Azure Logic App** we have been using for Azure Service Bus that was deployed in their environment but the AWS SNS connector exists only for AWS SQS.

What are my options to connect to the AWS SNS Topic from Azure?

Thanks,
grajee

Comment: Setup a HTTP endpoint subscription in the SNS topic and route the messages to the LogicApp like that. Of course, you’d need to change your trigger on the LogicApp to be “When a HTTP request is received.”

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html